# How to Fetch Text from two separate div's with same class name?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have to fetch two labels 'Text 1', 'Text 2' which belongs to same class ='xyz', which are located in two div's.Structure as shown below.

```
<div class='xyz'>TEXT 1</div>
<div class='xyz'>TEXT 2</div>
```

Can anyone please help me to solve this ?

Comment: Please post relevant HTML markup.

Comment: what you could do is use cssSelector and use driver.findELements(By.cssSelector(".xyz > div:nth-of-child(1)"))  or you can use the findElements and there u iterate over the list and get the text of each element. Ex: List<WebElement> aux = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".xyz"));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You find elements by [`className`](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#by-class-name) and then use `getText()` to get the text:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.className("xyz"));

for(WebElement element:elements) {
    System.out.println(element.getText());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `FindElements` method and then access to necessary div using index, e.g:

```
var elements = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector((".xyz"));
//get text in first element;
elements[0].getText();
//in second
elements[1].getText(); //etc
```