# How do we crawl and fetch the data from multiple div tags having same class name?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Sample Crawl</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="software">
            <h3>Company 1</h3>
            <p>Google</p>
        </div>
        <div class="software">
            <h3>Company 2</h3>
            <p>Facebook</p>
        </div>
        <div class="software">
            <h3>Company 3</h3>
            <p>Github</p>
        </div>
        <div class="software">
            <h3>Company 4</h3>
            <p>Yahoo</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Below I wrote the code to fetch contents of single div tag

```
    driver.find_element(:xpath => "//div[@class='software']/h3").text
    driver.find_element(:xpath => "//div[@class='software']/p").text
```

But I am not able to traverse each div tag having same class="software"

Comment: I got the answer This is answered in the below link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25606339/how-to-fetch-text-from-two-separate-divs-with-same-class-name?rq=1

Comment: You can implement the same logic using ruby